# Read multipart/form-data post request with Flask

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, multipartform-data

I am writing a server in python using Flask. 
And I know I am going to receive a request that it's type is multipart.
These are the requests headers I receive from the post request:

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Content-Length:

X-Data-Length: 8010

Host: ******

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=********

*This is how I receive the request:

```
@app.route('/***', methods == ['POST'])
    def some_function():
        print request.headers
        mp_data = decoder.MultipartDecoder.from_response(request)

        for part in multipart_data.parts:
            print(part.content)
            print(part.headers)
```

How am I supposed to retrieve the file sent to me in that request?
I have tried using request-toolbelt MultipartDecoder but got lost trying to do so.

Any help solving this would be appreciated.

- The code was taken from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33370069/10306617

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to retrieve the file send from the client, you can use `request.files`, it's a dict that maps the name of upload field (`<input type="file">`) with the file object.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to retrieve a photo sent to me. The photo is sent as an np array, which is encoded as a multipart form-data.
I tried what you suggested but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide the HTML code that uesd to upload images.

Comment: I am using an external service so I don't know how it builds the request.