# How to access data from WSGIRequest body?

Tags: python, wsgi

I want to get data received from URL request but I can't access it following is my code

```
def save_stripe_info(request):
    data = request.body
    email = data[0]
    payment_method_id = data[1]
    print('mail=>  ',email,'  i=>  ',payment_method_id, 'hello =>  ',data)
    # some code
```

it is printing the following output

```
mail=>   45   i=>   45 hello =>   b'------WebKitFormBoundary2ndFleWNwV9sa24C\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="email"\r\n\r\ntesti@gmail.com\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary2ndFleWNwV9sa24C\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="payment_method_id"\r\n\r\npm_1K5wvrBbWBJ638dRyJJeYjnL\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary2ndFleWNwV9sa24C--\r\n'
```

and if I try email = data[email] it gives an error that list indices must be an integer.

how can I get **email** and **payment_method_id** from request.

I also tried

```
body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
body = json.loads(body_unicode)
content = body['email']
```

but this is giving error `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: It looks to me csv with `;` delimiter.

Comment: It seems to me that your question is similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573332/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0

Comment: It is multipart data, indicated by repeatedly transmitted: `------WebKitFormBoundary...\r\n` sections. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369306/parse-multipart-form-data-received-from-requests-post. If possible try to change the content-type client side, parsing JSON is easier.