# Python equivalent to PHPs parse_ini_string

Tags: python, ini

I'm currently porting a PHP script to Python to learn Python.
But currently I'm stuck, because I'm calling an API which always returns an ini-formatted answer something like this:

```
error=0
---
asin=
name=Haftnotizen
detailname=info flags Haftnotizen
vendor=GlobalNotes
maincat=Haushalt, Büro
---
```

I've already learnt that I can use `ConfigParser` to parse ini-files.
But in this case, the ini-answer has no headings (which wouldn't be a problem with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25493615/3462319)) and also has these `---` separators.

My code right now is:

```py
import configparser

with open('test.ini', 'r') as f:
    config_string = '[dummy_section]\n' + f.read()
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read_string(config_string)
```

but unfortunately it's throwing the following error message at me:

```sh
configparser.ParsingError: Source contains parsing errors: '<string>'
        [line  3]: '---\n'
        [line  9]: '---'
```

How can I ignore those lines? (Also, they're not always in the same line)

I don't know what to do next, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: you may find mutli form toolkit helpful, example use in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369306/parse-multipart-form-data-received-from-requests-post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty, but if the error string is always exactly the same you can just remove that substring from the data. You would do that with this:

```
config_string = config_string.replace("---", "")
```

Comment: If I get you right, the code should then look like this:

with open('test.ini', 'r') as f:
    config_string = '[dummy_section]\n' + f.read()
    config_string = config_string.replace("---", "")
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
test = config.read_string(config_string)

But now I'm getting only "None" as a result..

Comment: Yes, that looks right

Comment: So, your answer works but I'm still not getting an answer unfortunately.. Thank you anyways! :)