# How to download excel attachment from message attachment from a mail in python using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: python, python-requests, attachment, microsoft-graph-api

I receive emails every week, and these mails are structured as follows :
Core mail with a message attachment ( an another email ) -> and in this second email, contains ax excel file that I want to download.

I'm using python and microsoft GRAPH API with the request : [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{1stmail}/attachments/{attachmentOf1stMail}/$value](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/%7B1stmail%7D/attachments/%7BattachmentOf1stMail%7D/$value)

I managed to access my excel sub-file like this : [screen from the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5y2T.png)

But now I want to download only the file, and access it locally.
Can I have some help to perform this ?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369306/parse-multipart-form-data-received-from-requests-post you need to decode it

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.