# Parse "multipart/form-data" payload while preserving order of parts in Python

Tags: python, post, multipart

I am building an HTTP server that accepts multiple input images, while images can be input as image files or as buffers.

For example, a request command may look as follows:

```
$ curl -F image_file=@/path/to/image1.jpg \
       -F image_file=@/path/to/image2.png \
       -F image_buffer=/path/to/image_buffer.bin -F image_buffer_shape="256,256,3" \
       -F image_file=@/path/to/image4.tif \
       <server URL>
```

The above command will send an HTTP POST request of `multipart/form-data` type, which will contain the following 5 parts in this order: `image_file, image_file, image_buffer, image_buffer_shape, image_file` - which is the order in which they were sent by the client.

The problem is that when using Python's built-in function `cgi.parse_multipart`, the result will be a dictionary of lists, which **loses the order** of inputs with different names. In my example, it will look as follows:

```
{'image_file' : [<content of image1.jpg>, <content of image2.png>, <content of image4.tif>],
 'image_buffer' : [<content of image_buffer.bin>],
 'image_buffer_shape' : ['256,256,3']
}
```

So in this example, there is no way to indicate that `image4.tif` was mentioned after `image_bufffer.bin`.

What would be the most "standard" and elegant way to parse the multipart payload while having access to the original index of each input?

#### Edit

My question referred to the scenario of using Python's built-in `cgi` module to parse the headers and the multipart payload. However, the `cgi` module turned out to have been deprecated.

For parsing the headers, there is no actual need to use the `cgi` module, since `self.headers` available in `BaseHTTPRequestHandler.do_POST` is of class `http.client.HTTPMessage`, which is a subclass of `email.message.Message`. This class provides standard methods to parse the headers (e.g., `self.headers.get_content_type()`, `self.headers.get_boundary()`, `self.headers.get("Content-Length")`).

For parsing the multipart payload, users may refer to 3rd party libraries or parse the data manually. To parse manually, it is possible to split the payload by the boundary (need to add leading `--` string when splitting), removing first and last parts (before the first boundary and after the last boundary), and passing each part to `email.message_from_bytes`. The resulting object will allow you to read the part's header fields (e.g., `.get_param('name', header='content-disposition')`), and to get the payload using `.get_payload(decode = True)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [parse multipart/form-data, received from requests post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369306/parse-multipart-form-data-received-from-requests-post)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thank you for the reference. I've checked this thread earlier. It can be useful, but all the answers there propose to use a 3rd party library, which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Well the cgi package that you are currently using is deprecated, so unless you are going to write that out yourself once you upgrade your python versions, you'd probably have to use external packages.

Comment: Wow, I missed that. They suggest some still-built-in alternatives [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0594/#cgi)

Answer (score 0):

Answering with a workaround that I have found:

Handling a POST request with multipart payload in Python may usually look as follows:

```
import http.server
import cgi

class MyHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers['content-type'])
        pdict['boundary'] = bytes(pdict['boundary'], 'utf-8')
        postvars = cgi.parse_multipart(self.rfile, pdict)
        # --- do somthing with the postvars dictionary ---
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write('whatever response...')
```

As explained in the question, the `postvars` dictionary returned by `cgi.parse_multipart` does not preserve the indices of the parts across different input names.

###### The workaround is to split the input by the boundary (including the boundary in the buffer), and inputting each resulting part to the `cgi.parse_multipart` function, so we can preserve the index by parsing the parts one by one.

- Be aware that the actual boundary has another leading '--' string.

The code may look as follows:

```
import http.server
import cgi
import io

class MyHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers['content-type'])
        boundary_for_manual_split = bytes('--' + pdict['boundary'], 'utf-8')
        pdict['boundary'] = bytes(pdict['boundary'], 'utf-8')
        content = self.rfile.read(int(self.headers['Content-Length']))
        all_boundary_indices = []
        start_index = 0
        while True:
            try:
                all_boundary_indices.append(content.index(boundary_for_manual_split, start_index))
                start_index = all_boundary_indices[-1]+1
            except:
                break
        all_boundary_indices.append(len(content))
        parts = [content[all_boundary_indices[i]:all_boundary_indices[i+1]] for i in range(len(all_boundary_indices) - 1)]
        postvar_list = []
        for i, part in enumerate(parts):
            postvars = cgi.parse_multipart(io.BytesIO(part), pdict)
            postvar_list.append(postvars.items())
        # --- do somthing with the postvar_list inputs ---
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write('whatever response...')
```

The above implementation creates the list `postvar_list`, which contains sorted tuples of input name and content.